# Android: Sharing data between native code (C) and application (java)

Tags: java, android, native, shared-memory, ashmem

I have a native app running on Android 5.0, an audio effect actually, that get launched on camcorder recording usecase (for instance). 
I have an application that needs to retrieve some data from it, 3 integers exaclty, that changes constantly.

How can a share these data from my native process with my application?

What are the options?

I had a look to ashmem but cannot find an example for my case,
I tried to write my data to a file and read them with from jni, but when I launch this read function, I dont see any trace of the native function (only the jni itself) and get constant random numbers... (but no crash)

Thanks,
Pierre

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the JNI documentation. There are many functions available for this of the form:

```
 env->GetShortArrayRegion(currentDim, 0, size, buffer[i]);
```

You can also pass a `long` pointer between your Java & C app that points to a native C/C++ structure.